# Неправильный формат url?

Tags: android

Всем привет. Подскажите является ли

```
file:///data/user/0/ru.xxxxxx.yyyyyyy/cache/cropped455675577.jpg
```

корректным url адресом файла, находящимся на устройстве???

Answer (score 2):

Судя по [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) - вполне себе является

Comment: просто дело в том, что этот url отправляется на backend, где сервер ругается что это не правильный url, вот и интересуюсь

Comment: @Nikita вероятно, на сервере такого файла нет, поэтому и ругается